# Google play tablet 7-inch screenshots

Tags: google-play

Google play console wants me to add some 7-inch tablet screenshots in order to make the app easily accessible to tablets. But I don't have any tablet. Don't understand what's the problem. I have made screenshots in the final phase of development, testing the game in the Unity editor. I suppose these .png images are as good as if they were made from a phone. I don't even know how to make screenshots from a phone.

Is there a hidden feature to identify a screenshot as being made from the 7-inch tablet? Why don't they simply state the image resolution they want for the tablet "screenshot"??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't matter what resolution your image is. Just upload the images to that section, the purpose of that section is only to let your users have a first look of what your app looks like before they install it. If you don't intend to make your app for Tablet, just let that section empty, upload images only to Phone's section.

If you are using an Android phone such as Samsung, I would recommend you have a look at `Settings/Advanced Features/ Smart Capture` (turn it on). Then you can swipe your screen to take a screenshots (it has a tutorial there)

Comment: Google Play now _requires_ the screenshots, so the section cannot be left empty. What should be done in this case?

Comment: Never mind, they simply have misleading UI/UX. It is possible to only upload phone screenshots.

Comment: @silver any reply on Jon queries ?

Comment: @Kamlesh If now Google Play requires the screenshots, you can take the screenshots directly from a real device or from an emulator such as Blue stacks or Genymotion.

Comment: I don't have tablet as well and don't want to make them in some emulator. I had to put phone screenshots everywhere otherwise I could not save (for new app). Then I edited the main shop presence again and deleted the tablet screenshots. I could save then. Quite buggy and misleading.

Comment: @Jon I've just uploaded two phone screenshots, left the tablet section empty, and I got no error message.

Comment: Dear tk_, it doesn't matter the screenshots are the real ones from corresponding devices. They are the ones to help your customers (users) have a good view about your app/game before they decide to install it. So it depends on you how you deliver the first experience to your potential users (customers)